# import CSV into mysql table via command prompt (MySQL 5.6.25)

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-5.6, csv, command-line

I'm trying to load CSV's into a mysql database with this command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '\Users\userName\Downloads\tableName.csv' 
INTO TABLE tableName 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

But I recieve this error:

```
ERROR 2 <HY000>: File 'UsersuserNameDownloadstableName.csv' not found <Errocode: 2 - No such file or directory>
```

I log onto mysql with the command (as described here [MySQL import csv file ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of /path/file.csv (Errcode: 2)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55960/mysql-import-csv-file-error-13-hy000-cant-get-stat-of-path-file-csv-errcod)):

```
mysql -u root -p --local-infile
```

doing what was described in the link above I was able to import the CSV's on a different MySQL Server (On a seperate machine running Ubuntu).  However the same process doesn't seem to be working for a differente MySQL Server instance on a Windows machine using Command Prompt.

Comment: If you're running the command `mysql -u root -p --local-infile` I assume your MySQL Server is on your local machine, but you said *on an Ubuntu machine*, can you edit your question and add which one is your *client* and your *server* (Ubuntu?).

Comment: You're not missing 'C:\"?

Comment: @oNare I added edits hope that clears up any confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is Windows we are dealing with, either use the double backslash

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\userName\\Downloads\\tableName.csv' 
INTO TABLE tableName 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

or the forward slash

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/userName/Downloads/tableName.csv' 
INTO TABLE tableName 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

[It says so in the MySQL Documentation on `LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

> The file name must be given as a literal string. On Windows, specify backslashes in path names as forward slashes or doubled backslashes. The character_set_filesystem system variable controls the interpretation of the file name.